# How to pass argument (file path) to a VBScript that forces a program to run *without* admin privilege?

Tags: vbscript

I want to force run an old game modding program (DragonAgeToolset.exe) without admin privilege. This is easy by creating a simple VBScript as follows:

```
set ws=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
ws.run "cmd /min /C ""set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start """" ""D:\Spiele\Dragon Age Origins\tools\DragonAgeToolset.exe""",0
```

But UAC will still pop up when I double click a mod file directly because it is associated to the exectuable file. I changed the file association in regedit from

> "D:\Spiele\Dragon Age Origins\tools\DragonAgeToolset.vbe" "%1"

to

> wscript.exe "D:\Spiele\Dragon Age Origins\tools\DAToolset.vbe" "%1"

and edited the VBScript accordingly. This is where I got lost and have no idea what to do:

```
set ws=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
if wscript.arguments.count > 0 then
    FileName=wscript.arguments(0)
else
    FileName=Empty
end if
ws.run "cmd /min /C ""set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start """" ""D:\Spiele\Dragon Age Origins\tools\DragonAgeToolset.exe"" " & FileName ,0
```

The VBScript will run normally without argument, but with any argument added things will go wrong and an error message (from windows explorer) will show:

> Cannot find "D:\Spiele\Dragon Age Origins\tools\DragonAgeToolset.exe D:\Spiele\Dragon Age Origins\MOD\modefile.mor". Please make sure the name is correct and repeat.

There lack quotes between the program and its parameter.

If I quote ***FileName*** once, namely change it to "FileName", the following error message (from Windows explorer) will show

> Cannot find "D:\Spiele\Dragon Age Origins\tools\DragonAgeToolset.exe FileName". Please make sure the name is correct and repeat.

If I double or quadrupole quote ***FileName***, VBScript Host will report a syntax error "ending is required".

If I triple quote ***FileName***, the toolset program I intend to run will start but complains it cannot find a file called "FileName".

I'm apparently lost in all the quoting drama.

Comment: A string in VBScript starts and ends with a single double quote (`"`), if you want to include literal double quotes in a string you escape them by doubling the quotes (`""`). Follow these simple rules and you can't go wrong.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding your `FileName` with double quotes, remembering what I said in the previous comment, give this a try - `FileName = """" & wscript.arguments(0) & """"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem I had was not that I forgot to add double quotes, but & symbols between """" and Filename.